# Prove a point $x\in \Bbb{R^n}$ is a zero-dimensional manifold

Tags: multivariable-calculus, manifolds, diffeomorphism

Let $x\in \Bbb{R^n}$. We may claim that there is an open $U$ containing $x$. For the proof, is it enough to define a diffeomorphism $h:U\to\emptyset$? This would mean that $$h(U\cap \{x\})=V\cap(\Bbb{R^0}\times\ \{0\})$$

and if we let $V=\emptyset$ also, then $$h(U\cap \{x\})=\emptyset$$

EDIT : Okay, I realize now, that generally proving things are manifolds by the definition is probably not practical. That being said, I would be interested to know whether a "proof by definition" is feasible. Intuitively this seems very simple. Every point of $\Bbb{R^n}$ resembles the origin, which is just a point.

Comment: Why do you claim that a $0$-dimensional Euclidean space is just the empty set?

Comment: Doesn't it follow from the fact that its basis is the empty set? Am I wrong about that as well?

Comment: Consider the empty linear combination.

Comment: That would be the same as the empty sum, which is zero. So $0$-dimensional space is just the set containing the origin . Which is closed under addition and scaling.

Comment: Depending on your definition of submanifolds:

Either set $f:\{0\}\to\mathbb R^n$ by $f(0) = x$. Then $f$ is an homeomorphism upon it’s image (quite trivially), so $\{0\}$ is a $0$-dim (global) manifold.

Another way would be: $\{x\}$ is the set defined by $f(y)=0$ for $f(y)=y-x$. $f$ has full rank, so $\{x\}$ would be a smooth (in fact $C^\omega$) $0$-dim manifold.